# Is it worth getting a MIMO network adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11n

I will be getting a new 802.11n adapter soon. Will getting a two-antenna MIMO adapter potentially improve bandwidth and/or signal quality if my router does not support MIMO? If yes, how should i position the two antennae?

Answer (score 0):

Getting a multiple-antenna MIMO adapter *will* improve bandwidth and signal even if your router does not support MIMO. However, it won't provide nearly as much benefit as you would get with a MIMO-enabled router.

In your case, the antennas will be used for *antenna diversity*, which has been around a lot longer than MIMO. While MIMO essentially sends two signals to double the speed, simple antenna diversity uses just combines the signal to increase signal strength, or chooses the strongest one as you move around. This gives a slight (10-20%) increase in speed as a result of better and more reliable signal strength.

The antenna should be positioned the same as any other multiple antenna router or adapter.

Answer (score -1):

MIMO powered receiver is very useful in cases where the router does not support 5 GHz and you want a higher link speed than 72mbit. Additional antennas will naturally increase signal quality, but not always the link speed. We would need your router specification and link speed expectations to give better advice.

Comment: None of this is relevant when the router does not support MIMO.